# Is there any way to get list of folder names in amazon s3 bucket?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am writing PHP script for uploading folders if not found in amazon S3 bucket using s3cmd  . For that first i need to get all folder names and store it in array and then check array using array_search if folder name is there or not and proceed to next step .

I used get_object_list and list_objects in PHP both will not return only folder names . So i wonder is there any way to do it .

Comment: S3 objects look like they have folders, but they don't really exist. You can look for a *prefix*. If this doesn't help, please list the commands you are trying and some examples of what you want.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 uses is **"flat" storage system**. It does not actually support folders/sub-directories. Rather, the sub-directory path is stored as part of the filename, known as the "key".

For example, `foo.txt` stored in a folder called `bar` actually creates an object with a key name of `bar/foo.txt`. When retrieving the object it appears as though it is in the bar directory, but it really isn't.

S3 does support the ability to retrieve a list of **Common Prefixes** that is effectively a list of directories, but there is no guarantee that such prefixes always exist, especially for empty directories.

Rather than writing a script to "upload folders if not found", take a look at the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It includes a command `aws s3 sync` that can automatically copy files between locations, including only copying new or modified files. That might totally avoid the need for you to write your own script.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is a cloud/object storage with a flat namespace. There is not concept of a folder or directory on Amazon S3. What you do have is a `key` and its `CommonPrefixes`

To get a similar feeling of POSIX one has use ListObjects() with special delimiters to provide an emulation for file system browsing.

https://github.com/minio/mc is built with such a purpose what you want is fairly easy to do in `mc`.

Here is an example approach on how you can see this working. `mc` features progress bar, session management, script friendly `--json` output and many more.

```
$ mc --json ls https://s3.amazonaws.com/miniocloud | jq 'if .type == "folder" then .name else empty end'
"G/"
"Go/"
"asdfasdfadsf/"
"bin/"
"ema/"
"emacs/"
"new/"
"te1231231231231231231231/"
"test/"
```